# Laravel /admin/login keeps redirecting to /login

Tags: php, laravel

My website will only have admins who can login, so I'm trying to remove the /login, and only leave /admin/login.

But now when I type /admin/login, I keep getting redirected to /login. I am not sure how to modify the login and authentication methods to stop getting redirected to /login.

When I set /login to a different redirect (404 error), I get "Route [login] not defined" whenever I try to /admin/login.

Comment: Why bother move /login to /admin/login if only admins there?

Answer (score 1):

Probably because you have something like this:

```
Route::middleware(['auth'])->group(function () {
   Route::get('/admin/login', ...);
});
```

Or

```
Route::get('/admin/login', function () {
    //
})->middleware('auth');
```

And so you cant access `/admin/login` if you are not logged in, and so the middleware will redirect you to the `/login` page

Solution: remove `auth` from the `middlewares`